# OWL parser for PHP?

Tags: php, rdf, owl, rdfa

I am asking just for clarification, may sound silly for some, but i am a newbie to semantic web world :)

From few days i have been experimenting on extracting RDF from HTML, trying to parse it and apply few SPARQL queries on it. I am currently using [ARC2 (PHP library)](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki).

But can i use the same([ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki)) even if the embedded is OWL?

will i be able to get full advantage of what OWL is intended for using ARC2?

if not what are the alternative libraries for that job (PHP)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an RDF [mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/) to OWL, so you can serialize OWL in any of the RDF formats and any standard RDF parser will be able to handle that.  I'm not clear what you mean by "full advantage" but if you mean perform reasoning, then no, probably not.  Reasoning doesn't have anything to do with parsing, and I don't think that ARC supports OWL reasoning.  For that, you're going to need an actual OWL reasoner such as [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/) or [HermiT](http://hermit-reasoner.com/).

I think ARC supports the ability to query against a SPARQL endpoint, so you could use something like [Joseki](http://joseki.org) to stand up an endpoint backed by a reasoner and be able to get some OWL joy that way.

Comment: Michael, could you maybe suggest a neat way to use any of the parser within a web application? Do I have to look for a Tomcat server provider, or is there a way to wrap the parser somehow and use it on a standard Apache server?

Comment: Can you create a separate question for this?  What are you parsing, what is your web app trying to do, etc.  Hard to recommend an approach without complete information.

Answer (score 2):

There's [pOWL](http://aksw.org/Projects/Powl.html) - also available [at SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powl/).

There's also [RAP, an RDF API for PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rdfapi-php/). (It seems that RAP may be more well documented, presently, at its regular [web site](http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/rdfapi/))

I haven't evaluated either, as yet, granted, but it looks like their respective codebases would be stable, I expect. I thought that I could as well share the links, my having developed a similar question, tonight. Cheers!